# shiny.js - method not called

Tags: javascript, r, methods, shiny

I've implemented a javascript-file that, show a loading screen while the shiny is busy. It didn't worked so I've debugged it and I've found that the function

```
   addMessageHandler('progress', function(message) {
      $(document.documentElement).addClass('shiny-busy');
      for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
      var key = message[i];
      var binding = this.$bindings[key];
      if (binding && binding.showProgress) {
         binding.showProgress(true);
      }
     }
   });
```

is never called. But the function that removes the class("shiny-busy") it's always called.
The problem seems to be here:

```
    // A function for sending messages to the appropriate handlers.
    // - msgObj: the object containing messages, with format {msgObj.foo, msObj.bar
    this._sendMessagesToHandlers = function(msgObj, handlers, handlerOrder) {
     // Dispatch messages to handlers, if handler is present
     for (var i = 0; i < handlerOrder.length; i++) {
     var msgType = handlerOrder[i];

    if (msgObj[msgType]) {  //when msgType = "progress", the if is false and so the function for addClass("shiny-busy") it's not called
      // Execute each handler with 'this' referring to the present value of
      // 'this'
      handlers[msgType].call(this, msgObj[msgType]);
    }
  }
};
```

How can/should I solve the problem?

Thank you!

EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED!

Comment: I'm not sure what your second code sample does. I guess it's a message sender, but what calls it? Why are you passing messages from javascript to javascript? You can call the 'progress' message handler directly from the R side, which should be much easier if the alert is about shiny-server being busy.

Comment: That is not my code, it is the code from the shiny.js - file and it is called automatically.